# Do NPCs have to roll Piloting in Slipstream?

Tags: savage-worlds, npc, vehicles, slipstream-setting

When the PCs travel from fragment to fragment as passengers on ships owned and piloted by NPCs, do I roll Piloting for the NPC pilot when the PC travel, and do I apply the modifiers for crossing the stream?

We've just played our third session of Slipstream, and I'm new to roleplaying, so I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: Hi uoji, and welcome to rpg.stackexchange! These are all potentially good questions, but as a single question it is too broad and might be put on hold - you might be better off asking them as individual questions to get more focused answers. Take the [tour] if you wish to learn more about how our site works. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Uoji, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. I see from your informed badge you've taken our [tour] by now, so thanks for doing that. We have a policy here of asking just one question per question except when those questions don't make sense being asked separately. I've removed all but your first question, but the rest are available by clicking the [edited X time ago](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/99605/revisions) link below your post. Please feel free to ask the others as separate questions. If you feel one or more *are* inseparable from this one, please do edit them back in.

Comment: I hope you enjoy it here, and when you reach 20 reputation, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Comment: @uoji are the said NPCs piloting the PCs ship or they are chasing PCs across fragments?

Comment: @ShadowKras no they travel NPC as passenger.

Comment: @uoji That last comment is confusing. Who is piloting and who are the passengers?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the PCs travel as passenger with the NPC. The NPC is the ower of the ship.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! I've edited your question to include that clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Chases: Yes, you should

Movement in slipstream is calculated based on a [square-divided map](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjSxqWupuXTAhVBEpAKHRwWBj4QjBwIBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshichitenhakki.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F02%2Fp1040128.jpg&psig=AFQjCNF3x-PVvbY73MpX9GXqXxlMiZFJpA&ust=1494504798127033), and a success on the Piloting check means the vessel moved the indicated **Travel Speed**. Each raise on the Piloting check increases the vessel's movement and should affect the outcome of an *inter-fragment* chase.

Which means that even if the PCs have a slower vessel, a good pilot can escape from faster vessels. The opposite might happen aswell.

Chases *brings tension* to the table, and it makes a good story, it is similar to a combat scene and the players might be expecting to test their Piloting skill against the enemy NPCs. So you definitelly should roll the NPCs Piloting to make this a contested scene against the PCs, specially if failure on these checks would lead to a combat scene between vessels.

### A NPC piloting the PC's vessel: Yes, if that is relevant to the story

If the PCs hired a NPC to pilot their ship, that either means they do not have a good pilot between themselves, or they don't want to focus on that part of the game system.

If they do not have a good pilot, and if it makes sense to the story and will add tension, you should *probably* make these checks, preferably opens rolls or ask for a PC responsible for this NPC to make these checks. This might be the case if the group of PCs are not enough to fill the entire crew of the vessel, like if they are in combat and need people to operate the guns, pilot the vessel *and* be an engineer all at the same time.

If they simply don't want to bother with the travelling aspect of the game, you should probably *hand-weave* these checks. Assume the NPC rolled an average result on his check, apply the bonuses and penalties, and see if that is enough to cross that fragment. Only bother with this check if they are attempting to cross the *Graveyard* or *Dust Cloud*, or if they are actually being chased or chasing another vessel.

Comment: Much better than my answer :)

Comment: Note that the question's been clarified.

Comment: Well, the answer was accepted as is. Should i edit to cover the scenario described on the question and remove the ones that weren't (the two on my answer)? Or simply add another topic and keep what was already written as is?